# Android localization/translation

Tags: localization, translation

I have a keyboard app designed for Serbian language. My keys have labels based in Serbian cyrillic alphabet. My xml strings that are used for those labels are enclosed in `<xliff:g></xliff:g>` tags, but a certain provider on a certain type of a phone still translates these into a different language. Just in case, I also have my strings in language specific folders, but it still happens. Does anyone know if there is a way I could disable translating of all my strings any other way?

Answer (score -1):

There are providers who can handle technical files translations,i.e. know what to translate in technical files. Also, some are available for you to manage the translations. OneSky is one of these platform and we also provide translation service.

[See GIF of how placeholder validation works in OneSky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TioXu.gif)

Disclaimer: I work in OneSky